# jython setup in Eclipse/PyCharm

Tags: java, python, macos, python-2.7, pycharm

Using Python 2.7 on Mac, and IDE is PyCharm. Need to use some Java functions inside Python script, and prefer to use import of Python, for example `from com.a.b.c import fooFunc`, so that I can use `fooFunc` in Python script as a Python function. The Java functions are defined in `goo.jar`.

My question is, where should I place the `goo.jar` file, so that Python/PyCharm could find the jar file?

**Edit 1**, add screen snapshot for PyDev for Jython project,

[image]
[image]

**Edit 2**, add screen snapshot for auto-config error message,

[image]

**Edit 3**, cannot select installed jython interpreter from Eclipse,
[image]
[image]

**Edit 4**, can only select .jar file when configuring jython interpreter,

[image]

**Edit 5**, program runs ok but with red alert error messages from console,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Python by itself has no wrappers around the java framework, therefore there is no way for it to import java classes or use java methods. You need to make use of jython. The [jython book](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html) has a chapter on how to use jython in an IDE

Comment: @khredos, thanks and vote up. I followed the guide and confused by the following statement, 

Once you have selected the ‘Interpreter – Jython’ section, you will be presented with an empty list of Jython interpreters at the top of the right side. We clearly need to fix that! So, click the New button, enter ‘Jython 2.5.1’ as the Interpreter Name, click Browse, and find jython.jar inside your Jython 2.5.1 installation.

Comment: @khredos, (cont'd), my confusion is it seems PyDev is just a toolkit? And I need to install Jython separately, correct? If so, would you mind to point me some guide how to install Jython on Mac OSX (which could be used together as PyDev Eclipse plug-in)? Thanks.

Comment: Your IDE isn't really PyCharm - it's Eclipse + PyDev. Any reason for mentioning / tagging the question with PyCharm?

Comment: @sebastian, good question and vote up, actually I prefer to use PyCharm. But from the discussion, if I need to import java package into a Python program, I have to use PyDev + Eclipse (which support jython)? Is there a solution to use Java package inside Python program using PyCharm?

Comment: I haven't used Jython - but PyCharm should support it just fine: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-sdk.html

Comment: @sebastian, vote up for the reply and wondering do you have any experience how to import java package into a python script in PyCharm? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow up on the comments above, yes if you are using pydev for Eclipse, then that's just the plugin that allows for writing python code with Eclipse. To install Jython, there are a number of guides out there, but it boils down to a two step process:

1. [Download and install](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.python%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jython-installer%22) Jython. The installation process will usually tell you where Jython is installed
2. Next [Configure your IDE](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter11/) to include the location of jython. As the JetBrains family of IDE's are very much the same, the way I added Jython to IntelliJ was **File > Project Structure > SDK > + > Python SDK > Navigate to the Jython Binary**

Also take some time to peruse the [Jython Book](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up for your reply. I tried to create a new project of type PyDev, it seems there is already an option of Jython? Does it mean Jython already installed? Is there a way to check if Jython is already installed? Please refer to **Edit 1** section of edited post.

Comment: @LinMa Press that link on the first image that says "Please configure an interpreter before proceeding", this should give you the option to navigate to the install location of jython, then pycharm shall do the rest

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up. Add screen snapshot in **Edit 2** section for error message when select auto-config. Does it mean Jython is not installed? Is there a way to check if Jython is installed somewhere?

Comment: @LinMa Did install jython? If so, where did the installer install jython?

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up. I mean this is no my dedicated computer, and is a shared work station which I have sudo access. Just want to learn from you if I have a way to check if Jython is already installed somewhere, so that I do not need to install again? :)

Comment: @LinMa If you visit the command prompt and type `jython` and get an error message or something to the same effect, then jython is not installed. You can also type something like `which jython` or `command -v jython`. If nothing promising shows up, then you most likely don't have jython installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116416/discussion-between-khredos-and-lin-ma).

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up. What do you mean `command -v`? Is there a command in Linux called `command`? :)

Comment: @LinMa Yes there is, you might not have it on osx by default but if you tried the other methods and couldn't find jython, then just use homebrew to install it

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up. I checked the Central Repository page you referred for jython, it seems there is no install command? Sorry for asking this dumb question, I always use pip, anaconda or yum/rpm for package install, never used the Central Repository you mentioned. :)

Comment: @LinMa Under the download section, you click [jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-installer/2.7.1b3/jython-installer-2.7.1b3.jar). This will download the jar file to your machine, then run the command `java -jar location/of/the/jar/you/download`

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up and installed successfully (use the graphical interface), but when I execute command like `jython` or `which jython` still no output. If you have any further thoughts to verify the installation, it will be great.

Comment: @LinMa That's ok, now you just need to open pycharm again and navigate to the location of jython

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up. Please refer to **edit 3** for the new screen snapshots, it seems I cannot select the location of the interpreter -- there is a forbidden sign around directory root. I install under directory `/private/var/root/jython2.7.1b3/jython.jar`, if you have any further thoughts, it will be great.

Comment: @LinMa you need to navigate to the `bin` directory under `jython2.7.1b3`. There you will find `jython`, that's what you want. Note there is no `.jar` extension

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up and it seems I can only select .jar file when configuring jython interpreter. Please refer to **Edit 4** section for screen snapshot for updated post. From the link you referred (http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html#minimal-configuration), it seems we can only select .jar as well. If you have any further comments, it will be great.

Comment: @LinMa Ok try selecting the jar, but this time enter a name for the interpreter (from picture 3). Name it something like `Jython2.7.1b3`

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up and tried the sample program at, http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html#hello-pydev-creating-projects-and-executing-modules, it works with PyDev project with jython interpreter. But it has error message each time I run, error message like this, is it a key error? I post it as **edit 5** section of the post,

`*sys-package-mgr*: can't write cache file for '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: can't write index file`

Comment: @LinMa The reason for this is that you have installed jython in a place where it does not have write access to. In this case, it is trying to create a cache directory in the place where it was installed, but the filesystem permissions are not set for doing that. Possible solutions include reinstall it somewhere a non root user will have access to it, remove and reinstall it using homebrew (as I mentioned before). [Someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758458/sys-package-mgr-cant-create-package-cache-dir-when-run-python-script-with-j) might have seen this before. Gl and gnite

Comment: Thanks khredos, vote up and such error are index/cache related, I think they are only related to performance boost and has nothing to do with functional?

Comment: Thanks khredos, mark your reply as answer. Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: There is no more File -> Project Structure, not sure when this changed

Comment: @JasonS: In PyCharm, open the File>Settings>[YourProjectName]>Project Interpreter>Add and select the Jython executable in [JyhonInstallDir]/bin/. This will register Jython interpreter. Then make sure you have selected Jython as the Project Interpreter and press Apply button followed by OK.